# how to test if a javascript cookie has expired?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to test if a javascript cookie has expired using?

I need to do a few thing conditionally and two of those conditions are overlapping for which if it could be tested whether a cookie has expired then it will be easier for me to get things done.

I am using `jquery-1.5.js` and `jquery.cookies.js` plugin.

Thanks.

**CODE**

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
jq(document).ready(function () {

    var timeStart, timeSubmit, timeLeft;
    timeSubmit = 5 * 60 * 1000;
    timeStart = jaaulde.utils.cookies.get("_watchman");
    try {
        if(jaaulde.utils.cookies.test()) {
            throw "err1";
        }
        else if(hasCookieExpired) {
            throw "err2";
        }
        else if(!timeStart) {
            jaaulde.utils.cookies.set("_watchman", String(new Date().getTime()), {path: '/path', expiresAt: new Date((new Date().getTime() + timeSubmit))});
            timeLeft = timeSubmit - (new Date().getTime() - Number(jaaulde.utils.cookies.get("_watchman")));
            timeCheck();
        }
        else {
            timeLeft = timeSubmit - (new Date().getTime() - Number(jaaulde.utils.cookies.get("_tts")));         

            timeCheck();
        }

    } catch(err) {
        //handle errors
    }

    function timeCheck() {
            if(timeLeft <= 0) {
                triggerSubmit();
            }
            else {
                setTimeout(triggerSubmit, timeLeft);    
                setInterval(showTimeLeft, 1000);
            }       
    }

    function triggerSubmit() {
        //submit it
    }

    function showTimeLeft() {
        //do something
    }

});
```

Comment: Please skip, show us the related code you're having issues with. It might help us to help you.

Comment: Have you tried to change `expiresAt:` to `expires:` ? https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: @roXon: No, I didn't. The documentation had `expiresAt` so I used that. http://code.google.com/p/cookies/wiki/Documentation#Options_object shows `expiresAt`.

Comment: Let me try `expires` and see if it works properly.

Comment: Ah... I misunderstood the plugin as it's for only 1 letter *S* : jquery.cookie.js / jquery.cookies.js BTW... have you tried to use the other one? (sincerely I find a bit hard to read the code, I miss the other JS part, and a place to test things, so I just dropped an eye on that one)

Comment: @roXon: I am not sure but are they the same plugins?

Comment: No, cookie.js is by Klaus Hartl and cookies.js is by James Auldridge
I use the first one. Never had issues with it. But as I can see the one you use has more components.

Comment: @roXon: The related part in the other JS file is the 3 variable declared above in the code I posted later in the question. Rest of the part is some non-relevant ajax calls. In that JS as well if just a  test for expiration is needed if could be done before any other solution to think about. I might have written the code above poorly as I am barely a javascript guy. But the part that I have commented out is non-relevant part.

Comment: @roXon: Let me see if I could work around this issue or I might try the plugin you suggested.

Comment: Seems I cannot find any proper solution tho that one. Try the one I suggested. Let me know the results. (You might try also to find a more flexible solution to check that cookie) +1 for posting a relevant code to work with. Anyway

Comment: @roXon: I am not sure how does it work but when I look at the cookie in the mozilla forefox browser it shows the cookie with its value and shows the expiration time whichh suggests that it has expired and but when I retrieve the cookie value in the program it shows `null` for its value. So I am assuming that after cookie expiration, even if the browser doesn't delete it and still shows its non-null value it is always going to give `null` while programming.

Comment: The nulled cookie might not always be actually DELETED/ERASED (don't remember where I found this...) but it will be rather UNSET and as far as I know the data that is hold will NOT be relevant in the next cookie retrieval. Make sure you're not using '' quotes in `'null'` , cause that way you just change the cookie data to store the 'null' text/data

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
if( $.cookie('yourCookie') === null ) {
    // EXPIRED
} else {
    // DO SOMETHING ELSE
}
```

Or like this using *Ternary operator*:

```
$.cookie('yourCookie') === null ? /* EXPIRED */ : /* DO SOMETHING ELSE */;
```

---

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie (No longer maintained, archived)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie
https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Comment: But the cookie that has expired does have a non-null value. I see it having a value that I set it with but it has expired as with the time I set for it to expire. Now the user has signed, gone, browser has been closed and but that expired cookie is there. Will `if( $.cookie('yourCookie') == null )` still work in that case?

Comment: I have small troubles to understand your English and your thoughts. You want at user sign-Out to delete the cookie?

Comment: @skip may you please add the related code into your question?

Comment: I set a cookie with a value and the time after which it should expire and. There is a delete method to delete the cookie but that method couldn't run because user just signed out. Now the cookie is there and a timer is on. I need to test whether that user is coming after the countdown is over or while the countdown is still running as I need to handle these cases differently. So if I could just figure out if the cookie has expired I will be able to get things done easily.

Comment: Without seeing the code I can just suggest you to trigger the _cookie_ deletion on the *Sign Out* action (I suppose you use a 'click' action) `$('#sign_out').click(function(){$.cookie("yourCookie", null);
});`

Comment: Have added the code and added the relevent part here. There is another javascript on another page that is related to the variables declared in this file. So If the cookie could just be tested for expiration it wouldnt get any simpler for getting things done.

Comment: thanks...but use $.cookie('yourCookie') === undefined

Answer (score 12):

A browser will automatically remove any cookie once it expires, so all you need to do is check whether the cookie exists or not.

Comment: The browser hasn't done that and that's what the problem is. Its Mozilla firefox I am using and I haven't changed any settings.

Answer (score 4):

If you say that the browser did not remove the cookie, it's probably because your time zone is different from UTC.

Answer (score 2):

**To test, please enter below HTML code**

```
<label for="expsecs">Cookie expiration in seconds:</label>
<input type="text" id="expsecs" value="5" /><br />
<button id="setcookie">set cookie</button>
<button id="getcookie">get cookie</button>
<div id="cookiestatus">status</div>
```

**Please enter below jQuery code**

```
function set_cookie() {
    var secs = parseInt($('#expsecs').val(), 10);
    if (isNaN(secs)) {
        secs = 5;
    }
    var now = new Date();
    var exp = new Date(now.getTime() + secs*1000);
    var status = '';
    document.cookie = 'ExpirationCookieTest=1; expires='+exp.toUTCString();
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie.indexOf('ExpirationCookieTest=1') != -1) {
        status = 'Cookie successfully set. Expiration in '+secs+' seconds';
    } else {
        status = 'Cookie NOT set. Please make sure your browser is accepting cookies';
    }

    $('#cookiestatus').text(status);
}

function get_cookie() {
    var status = '';
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie.indexOf('ExpirationCookieTest=1') != -1) {
        status = 'Cookie is present';
    } else {
        status = 'Cookie is NOT present. It may be expired, or never set';
    }
    $('#cookiestatus').text(status);
}

function init() {
    $('#setcookie').bind('click', set_cookie);
    $('#getcookie').bind('click', get_cookie);
}

$(init);
```

**Check this in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fennrussel/5swpqcfv/embedded/result/)**