# How can I know a cookie whether is expired?

Tags: javascript, cookies, domdocument

How can I know a cookie whether is available?

In my browser, the Application -> Cookies, I can see the token's expire time.

But I can not use the `document.cookie` to get the expire time, so I don't know how to check whether is expired.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading cookie expiration date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532193/reading-cookie-expiration-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(document.cookie) { //if(document.cookie('yourCookie'))
    //DO SOMETHING
    console.log("Cookie exist!!!");
    console.log(true);
} else {
    // DO SOMETHING ELSE
    console.log("Cookie not exist!!!");
    console.log(false);
}
```

[Javascript cookie has expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9072385/how-to-test-if-a-javascript-cookie-has-expired)